# The first RadioButton is always checked even though I set the Checked properties to false on all the RadioButtons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple form with two `RadioButton`s. I wish both `RadioButton`s to be unchecked at the beginning of the application (no option selected by default), so that the user has to make a selection himself.

Although I set the `Checked` property to `false` on all the `RadioButton`s in the `Form` constructor and in the `Form` `Load` event handler, and I also called in the constructor a method that sets all the `Checked` properties of all the `RadioButton`s to `false`, when I run the application, the first `RadioButton` is still checked.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OptionSelection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;

        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        this.radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton_CheckedChanged);

        UncheckAllRadioButtons();
    }
    private void UncheckAllRadioButtons()
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> allControls = GetAllControlsOfDeterminedType(this, typeof(RadioButton));
        foreach (Control currentControl in allControls)
        {
            RadioButton _currentRadioButton = (RadioButton)currentControl;
            if (_currentRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                _currentRadioButton.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControlsOfDeterminedType(Control currentControl, Type type)
    {
       IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Control> allControls = currentControl.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return allControls.SelectMany(selectedControls => GetAllControlsOfDeterminedType(selectedControls, type)).Concat(allControls).Where(candidateControl => candidateControl.GetType() == type);
    }

    private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == (RadioButton)radioButton1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("radioButton1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("radioButton2");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code just to achieve such a little thing. You don't need any of that.

Comment: @ Racil Hilan I am sorry, but that does not help at all: 1. you do not point out what is wrong with my code. 2. you do not show me a better way to perform the task.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, it's just all redundant. The `Checked` property is set to `false` by default, and trying to set it to `false` over and over will not achieve anything. You have to look for what is setting it to `true` and stop it. See my answer.

Comment: @Racil Hilan All the existing code is posted. There is nothing more. All the redundant code is there only because by default the first RadiooButton was always checked. The funny thing is that after I closed Visual Studio and stared it again, it works as expected: all the RadioButtons are unchecked.

Comment: I understand that. It's not in your code. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Also, the entire `GetAllControlsOfDeterminedType` method could be replaced with just `Controls.OfType<DesiredType>()`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all that code. Simply set the `AutoCheck` property of the radio buttons to `false`.

If you want to set the `Checked` property to `false` in code, you'll have to do it after the form is displayed. So move your code from the `Load` event to the `Shown` event:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  radioButton1.Checked = false;
  //radioButton2.Checked = false;
}
```

You only need the first line, but it's your code.

By the way, the radio buttons are by default not checked when the form loads. The issue that you're facing is because your radio buttons are the first controls (or probably the only controls) on the form. So what happens is, when the form is displayed, the focus is moved to the first control, and that checks the radio button automatically. You can stop that by simply changing the `TabIndex` of the radio buttons so they are not the first control (you must have other controls on the form), or by setting the `TabStop` property of the radio buttons to `false`, so they don't get focused.

Comment: If I set the AutoChek property to false, it is true that all the RadioButtons are unchecked, but I am unable to check them when clicked by the mouse. As I said, it all works now, without having changed anything.

Comment: Yes, you will have to manually check/uncheck them in the `Click` event. See my updated answer for the correct way to uncheck them in code. Again, you don't need any of your long code.